# Database authentication with login form

Tags: php, database, authentication

I'm working on using a database to authenticate a user on a login form with php. I have the code below which is supposed to work, but when I click the "Try to Login" button, it waits and waits and waits, but nothing happens.

index.php:

```
// Needed when working with sessions
session_start();

// Variables that is true when the login goes wrong
$login_error = false;

if(isset($_POST['txtusername'])){

    // Load the login class en session class
    include("../Login.php");
    include("../Extensions/SessionLogin.php");

    // Create new instance of the SessionLogin class
    // Session login is just a simple extension upon the login class 
    // witch save the username in a session called user
    // This way the user doens't need to login again when reloading the page
    $Login = new SessionLogin();

    // Load the users data from users.xml file
    //$Login->InitXml("users.xml");
    $Login = new Login();
    $Login->InitDatabase("localost", "root", "root", "usernames", "user", "username", "password");
    $Login->SetPasswordEncoder("myhash");
    // Custom password encoder
    function myhash($password, $fields){
        return md5($password . "-" . $fields->salt_field);
    }

    // Check if the submitted information is correct
    if($Login->Test($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){

        // Login is correct
        // Do some extra code when login is ok
        // At this moment the session user is set with the username ($_SESSION['user'])

    }else{

        // Login is incorrect
        $login_error = true;

    }
}

// If action is set to logout then reset the session
// and refresh the page
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "logout"){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Easy login class</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <?php if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Login form</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <form action="" id="frmlogin" method="post" name="frmlogin" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input <?php if($login_error) echo 'class="error"'; ?> id="txtusername" name="txtusername" type="text" />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input <?php if($login_error) echo 'class="error"'; ?> id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" type="password" />
                <button type="submit" id="btnlogin">Try to login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>This is some very secret information that nobody is allowed to read without a user account :).</p>
            <p><a href="index.php?action=logout">Click here</a> to logout</p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Login.php (contains functions used in 'index.php'):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
$Login = new Login();
$Login->InitDatabase("10.0.100.55", "root", "DMaX", "wiki", "wp_users", "user_login", "user_pass");
$Login->SetPasswordEncoder("custom");
if($Login->Test("admin", "test")){
    echo "Login ok";
}else{
    echo $Login->GetError() . "<br />";
    echo "Login fout";
}

function custom($password, $fields=""){
    return md5($password . $fields->user_nicename);
}*/


/**
 * Universal login class
 *
 */
class Login {

    /**
     * Error messages
     */
    const ERROR_EMPTY_FIELD = "Make sure you fill username and password field.";
    const ERROR_WRONG_LOGIN = "Your username or password was incorrect.";

    /**
     * Characters that is used in CSV to separate fields
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CSV_SEPARATOR = ";";

    /**
     * Datasources
     */
    const SOURCE_CSV    = "csv";
    const SOURCE_XML    = "xml";
    const SOURCE_DB     = "db";

    /**
     * Array that holds usernames and passwords
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $_users = array();

    /**
     * String that holds the current error
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_error_string = "";

    /**
     * String that holds the current datasource
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_datasource = "";

    /**
     * Encoding function for the password
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_pass_encoding_func = "";

    /**
     * Database connection
     * 
     * @var resource
     */
    private $_database = "";

    /**
     * Database user table info
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $_database_table = "";
    private $_database_user_field = "";
    private $_database_pass_field = "";

    public function __construct(){}

    /**
     * Use database as datasource
     *
     * @param string $host
     * @param string $user
     * @param string $pass
     * @param string $database
     * @param string $table
     * @param string $user_field
     * @param string $pass_field
     * @param int $port
     * @return bool
     */
    public function InitDatabase($host, $user, $pass, $database, $table, $user_field, $pass_field, $port=3306){
        $this->_datasource = Login::SOURCE_DB;
        $link = mysql_connect($host . ":" . $port, $user, $pass);
        if (!$link) {
            trigger_error("Could not connect to MySQL server.", E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($database,$link)){
             trigger_error("Could not select MySQL database " . $database . ".", E_USER_ERROR);
             return false;
        }
        $this->_database_table = $table;
        $this->_database_user_field = $user_field;
        $this->_database_pass_field = $pass_field;
        $this->_database = $link;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Use XML file as datasource
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return void
     */
    public function InitXml($file){
        $this->_datasource = Login::SOURCE_XML;
        $this->readFile($file, "xml");
    }

    /**
     * Use Csv file as datasource
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return void
     */
    public function InitCsv($file){
        $this->_datasource = Login::SOURCE_CSV;
        $this->readFile($file, "csv");
    }

    /**
     * Select function to encode/hash the password
     *
     * @param string $function
     * @return bool;
     */
    public function SetPasswordEncoder($function="md5"){
        if($function != "" && function_exists($function)){
            $this->_pass_encoding_func = $function;
            return true;
        }else{
            trigger_error("This encoding function can't be used.", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test if login data is correct
     *
     * @param string $user
     * @param string $pass
     * @return bool/object
     */
    public function Test($user="", $pass=""){
        if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){
            return $this->tryLogin($user, $pass);
        }else{
            $this->_error_string = Login::ERROR_EMPTY_FIELD;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get error string if something has gone wrong
     *
     * @return string/bool
     */
    public function GetError(){
        if(!empty($this->_error_string)){
            return $this->_error_string;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Load data from file
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @param string $type
     */
    private function readFile($file, $type="xml"){

        // Read content of the file
        $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
        $content = fread($fh, filesize($file));
        fclose($fh);

        if($type=="xml"){
            $Xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
            foreach ($Xml->user as $user){
                $this->_users[] = array("username" => trim($user->username), "password" => trim($user->password));
            }
        }else{
            $lines = explode("\n", $content);
            foreach ($lines as $line){
                $parts = explode(Login::CSV_SEPARATOR , $line);
                if(isset($parts[0]) && isset($parts[1])){
                    $this->_users[] = array("username" => trim($parts[0]), "password" => trim($parts[1]));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Try to do a login
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return bool/object
     */
    private function tryLogin($username, $password){

        // Send error if there is not datasource set
        if(empty($this->_datasource)) trigger_error("There is no datasource set (Database/Xml/Csv)", E_USER_ERROR);

        switch ($this->_datasource){
            case Login::SOURCE_DB:
                $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->_database_table . " WHERE " . $this->_database_user_field . "='" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                    if(!empty($this->_pass_encoding_func)){
                        $password = $this->passwordEncoding($password, $data);
                    }
                    $pass_field = $this->_database_pass_field;
                    if($data->$pass_field == $password) return $data;
                }
                break;
            case Login::SOURCE_CSV:
            case Login::SOURCE_XML:

                // Encode password
                if(!empty($this->_pass_encoding_func)){
                    $password = $this->passwordEncoding($password);
                }
                foreach ($this->_users as $user){
                    if($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        $this->_error_string = Login::ERROR_WRONG_LOGIN;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get current url
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    private function currentUrl(){
        return "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }

    /**
     * Call password encoding
     * 
     * @param string $password
     * @param array/object $data
     * @return string
     */
    private function passwordEncoding($password, $data=null){
        if(in_array($this->_pass_encoding_func, array("md5", "sha1"))){
            return call_user_func_array($this->_pass_encoding_func, array($password));
        }else{
            return call_user_func_array($this->_pass_encoding_func, array($password, $data));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This `localost` should be `localhost` unless it's a typo. If it isn't a typo, then that's most likely the reason.

Comment: please do dome basic debugging to track down the location of the problem